# What is the relation between homotopy groups and homology?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

It's pretty much all said in the title, I don't need very specific answers, but I'd like to know the relations between those two properties (for example, if we know the homology of a topological space, can we infer something about it's fundamental group or his omotopy groups?)

Comment: the first homology group is the abelianization of the fundamental group. Proof and details are in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heI8d4NTa2c&list=PLpRLWqLFLVTCL15U6N3o35g4uhMSBVA2b&index=25
Or in Hatcher's algebraic topology.

Comment: If it is helpful, you may see this decade-old post In MathOverflow for further/deeper comparison - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24671/why-do-the-homology-groups-capture-holes-in-a-space-better-than-the-homotopy-gro

Comment: More generally, we have the [Hurewicz Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As commented above the [Hurewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem) computes some homology groups from the knowledge of homotopy groups; it indicates that homotopy groups are harder to compute than homology groups. In degree 1 the fundamental group can be nonabelian, and Hurewicz says that $H_1$ (with $\mathbb Z$ coefficients where not specified) is the abelianization of $\pi_1$. We cannot in general compute $\pi_1(X)$ knowing $H_1(X)$; historically the first example of this was found by Henri Poincaré, the [Poincaré dodecahedral space](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Poincar%C3%A9%27s_homology_sphere), which is a homology sphere -it has the homology of a 3-sphere- but has fundamental group $A_5$, the alternating group on 5 symbols, which is perfect, that is equal to its commutator, therefore with trivial abelianization. It seems that Poincaré formulated his [famous conjecture on 3-manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture) in 1904: 3-manifolds with the same homotopy groups as $S^3$ are homeomorphic (and diffeomorphic) to $S^3$, this was in his last opus on topology, "Cinquième complément à l'analysis situs", where he also published the construction above. It seems to actually have been the 1st time he explicitly noted the difference between the fundamental group (which he defined in the first installment of his "Analysis situs" series in 1895) and the first homology group; so that this difference was not first publicly noticed on a wedge of circles -with $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)\cong\mathbb Z\ast\mathbb Z$, a free group on 2 generators. I would add that in homology you only count images of simplices with multiplicities, while in homotopy you take the map into account not just its image -you quotient by homotopies but that still retains much of the coarse structure of maps-, which remembers a certain kind of order on the objects you count -the counts being recorded as groups. This intuition is made precise by the Hurewicz theorem for the fundamental group. Its proof can be found in Hatcher's [Algebraic topology](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf), chapter 2 for degree 1 and chapter 4 for higher degree. Higher homotopy groups are abelian because on $S^n$ there is a homotopy between the identity and the self-homeomorphism of the sphere which exchanges hemisphere while fixing the base point, so that you can make a homotopy betwee $f\star g$ and $g\star f$ for $f, g\in\pi_n(X)$. The Hurewicz theorem states that, for $X$ $(n-1)$-connected, sending a homotopy class of maps $S^n\rightarrow X$ to a cycle class in $H_n(X)$, is an isomorphism - between the first nonvanishing homotopy and reduced homology groups, in particular reduced homology vanishes in degree below $n$.

That principle also explains why higher homotopy groups of spheres are nontrivial while higher (than the dimension of your sphere) homology of spheres is trivial. To see this consider a sphere bundle over a sphere $p:X\rightarrow S^n$, with fiber $S^k$. You may begin with a fiber bundle with ball fiber $B^{n+1}$ and take a sphere one dimension lower $S^n$ inside each fiber; the resulting bundle is a retract of, thus homotopy equivalent to, the original bundle. It may happen that $X$ is itself a sphere $p:S^{n+k}\rightarrow S^n$, so we have an element of the homotopy group $\pi_{n+k}S^n$. Now a map of a sphere also yields a singular cycle of dimension $n+k$ thus an element $[p]\in H_{n+k}(S^n)$, but the cycle must be a boundary as the homology for $k>0$ is trivial. You can see this from the long exact sequence in homology, bootstrapping the dimension $0$ case (a point) where you have only 1 singular simplex in each degree and the differential is exact as in even degrees it has kernel $\mathbb Z$ and image $0$ and in odd degrees kernel $0$ and image $\mathbb Z$ -you may check Hatcher's [Algebraic topology](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf), p110 and the sample computations around there-; and for the intuition without using an exact sequence you can take as cycle the boundary of a standard simplex of dimension $n+k$, but this squishes down to only one of its faces so it is not anymore a sphere but a face (an $n+k-1$-simplex) so it is a trivial $n+k$-cycle. This happens because the order does not matter, when we sum a singular simplex and another one with the same image counted with multiplicity, their difference in homology will be $0$, so intuitively we are back to the case of $X=\{\ast\}$ a point placed in degree $n$ with all higher singular cycles with the same image, and the differential being exact as above. In particular if we see that a circle fibration over a sphere with a sphere as total space, $S^1\hookrightarrow S^{n+1}\xrightarrow{p} S^n$ always yields a trivial homology class $[p]\in H_{n+1}(S^n)$. But in homotopy the "cancellation of simplices with the same image" does not happen in general; if for instance we piece a path out of small trivial segments, the order in which we piece them will be remembered to some extent by homotopy; and in higher degree although $\pi_n$ maps from spheres still remember how they are put together as the following indicates. The simplest nontrivial element of a homotopy group of a sphere in degree higher than the dimension $n$ is, with $n=2$, the (homotopy class of the) [Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration) $S^1\hookrightarrow S^3\xrightarrow{p} S^2$, it remembers how the circles in each fiber are pieced together, even though they are all projected to a point. As a circle bundle the Hopf fibration is not trivial, not homeomorphic to the trivial bundle: for instance its total space has trivial fundamental group, $\pi_1(S^3)=0$, while the trivial circle fibration has $\pi_1(S^2\times S^1)=\mathbb Z$. But now a trivial fibration $p$ over $X$ yields a trivial element in $\pi_{n+k}X$ and conversely if $p$ is homotopic to a constant map to $X$ you can construct from your trivializing homotopy a global section which forms a basis in the corresponding $R^2$-bundle, so we have that the Hopf fibration makes $\pi_3(S^2)\neq 0$ -in fact it is freely generated by the Hopf map $p$ as can be seen from the long exact sequence of homotopy groups of a fibration, thus $\pi_3(S^2)=\mathbb Z$. In the end we see that because "homotopy cycles" remember the map, their parametrization, the order in which local pieces are pieced together, they are more complicated than homology cycles.

Here is another connection between homotopy and homology: [Eilenberg-MacLane spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space) $K(\pi,n)$ are CW-complexes that have a single nonvanishing homotopy group. They represent cohomology: $[X,K(\pi,n)]=H^n(X,\pi)$. We have that $S^1$ is a $K(\mathbb Z,1)$ space, so that $H^1(X)=[X,S^1]$ and $\pi_1(X)=[S^1,X]$. In the case $X=S^1\vee S^1$ we have $[X,S^1]\cong\mathbb Z^2$ (free abelian on 2 generators) and $[S^1,X]\cong\mathbb Z\ast\mathbb Z$ (free on 2 generators).

Let's also mention the [Dold-Thom theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dold%E2%80%93Thom_theorem) which computes the reduced homology of $X$ as the homotopy groups of a highly symmetrized version of $X$, $Sym^\infty(X)$: $\tilde{H}_n(X)\cong\pi_n Sym^\infty(X)$. For $S^2$ the infinite symmetric product is $\mathbb C\mathbb P^\infty$ which therefore has a single nonvanishing homotopy group $\pi_i Sym^\infty(S^2)\cong\pi_i(\mathbb C\mathbb P^\infty)\cong \tilde{H}_i(S^2)$, which is $\mathbb Z$ for $i=2$ and $0$ otherwise, thus $\mathbb C\mathbb P^\infty$ is a $K(\mathbb Z,2)$. The interval $I=[0,1]$ has $Sym^\infty(I)\cong\Delta^\infty\subset\mathbb R^\infty$ the infinite standard simplex which is contractible. $S^1$ has $Sym^n(S^1)$ homotopy equivalent to the space $Sym^n(\mathbb C\setminus\{0\})$ which is homeomorphic to the space of monic polynomials of degree $n$ with nonzero constant term, that is $\mathbb C^{n-1}\times\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$; this retracts to $S^1$ for all $n$ and when taking the infinite union $Sym^\infty(S^1)$ we still have a homotopy equivalence with $S^1$. The Dold-Thom theorem can be proved showing that it defines a homology theory; the key difficulty is to prove exactness, and the symmetric products yield quasifibrations when quotienting by a subspace in appropriate $n$, thus a long exact sequence of homotopy groups.

More generally, your question is so nontrivial that it is actually a central idea in algebraic topology, still actively researched, to use homology and generalized homology theories to approximate homotopy, the former being much easier to compute and actually effectively computable in many cases. But some fundamental problems remain open: most fundamental of all, the stable homotopy groups of spheres form the graded coefficient ring of the generalized homology associated to the sphere spectrum, that is by definition this generalized homology of the point -i think it is expected that this is the most difficult computation, as for a space $X$ the general properties of (co)homology give a large toolkit to compute (co)homology of $X$ from its coefficient ring. The Hurewicz theorem is one example how to pass from homotopy to homology; and a major example of advanced implementation of this idea, which gets closer to the best answer to your precise question, is the [Adams spectral sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adams_spectral_sequence), which however does not recover the full homotopy groups of spheres (from homological computations) but only some of those in the stable range, where homotopy actually simplifies down to a generalized homology theory -called "stable homotopy homology theory". If you want the most advanced uses of homology to compute homotopy groups you have to go at least a step further, to the Adams-Novikov spectral sequence, which starts with complex cobordism a generalized cohomology, instead of classical (aka ordinary) cohomology as used in the Adams version; complex cobordism "has a complex orientation" -the most general such theory- and uses (stably complex) manifolds instead of the more flexible singular chains to probe a space. The main reference presenting all that is [Ravenel's book](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/mybooks/ravenel.pdf). I think that the Adams-Novikov SS is the basis for the most advanced computations, some of which use a yet more complicated cohomology theory, elliptic cohomology. But there are some specific homotopy groups, if only outside the stable range, which are not computable by those homological methods. Thus the relation between homotopy groups and homology is a very complicated one, with much still to explore.